# Windows phone 8.1 contact store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, contacts

In windows phone, as i understand every app can create/read/write its own contacts store. But it can only read from other contact stores which are created by other apps. Is there a possibility that one app can create multiple contact stores?

Comment: What do you mean by contacts store here?

Comment: Contact store = address book

Comment: If you can explain your question a bit more?

Comment: Hope you understand the question. thanks.

Comment: @Kulasangar - I guess he refers to the Contact store API in Windows Phone 8/8.1 Silverlight applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207034(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a single application can only have one custom Contact store. This is stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207024(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Creatingoropeningacontactstore) (under the section *Creating or opening a contact store*):

> ***Each Windows Phone app can have a single contact store***. You open the
>   store by calling CreateOrOpenAsync. The store will be created when you
>   call this method, if it doesn’t already exist. The overloaded version
>   of this method accepts a member of the ContactStoreSystemAccessMode
>   enumeration and a member of the ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode
>   enumeration, which specify how much access the system and other apps
>   have to your contact store.